# PHP pthreads Stop all threads if at least 1 thread did the job

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads

Hello i am building a PHP application with the pthreads extension.

The application opens X amount of threads to do a fast file search on a computer to find a file.

I want all the threads to stop if at least 1 of my threads found the file i wanted.

How can i handle this situation?

Thank you

Comment: pthreads is not a fairly thin wrapper ... Here's an introduction to the subject https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782

Answer (score 0):

I'd use memcache, during the scan for files it also check if the flag is true. If a thread finds the file it sets the flag to true, and once it's true you can exit the function on all the other threads with a break statement.